# How to remove non-AlphaNumeric character from LibreOffice Calc(generated by a Java Program) cell

Tags: java, cell, xls, libreoffice

I am using a Java program to extract the values from a SQLite file and storing them into an excel(.xls) file on UBUNTU.

As shown in snapshot, when integer values are store in the excel sheet a special character (') is being appended to the values(see formula bar in image) and hence values are being stored as String instead of int. Because of which I am not able to make chart using these values.

[image]

The java function I am using in the program is  -

```
photoInfo.add(resultSet.getString(h));
```

photoInfo is an arrayList and have no function to add integers.

I already tried formatting the cell as integer but of no use.

This character(') only appears in formula bar and is not visible in excel cell.

Can someone please suggest how can I remove this non-alphanumeric character from all the values in one go. Please provide code in StarBasic (not in VBS) if any is available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a new column.
Use formula

```
=$A1+0
```

[image]

and now extend this formula to all cells.

This is weired but works. And ofcourse is the most quick method I searched so far.

Answer (score 0):

Once the spreadsheet has been set up and you are ready to make charts, run this tiny VBA macro:

```
Sub tic_killer()
For Each r In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    If r.PrefixCharacter = "'" Then
        r.Value = r.Value
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Its throwing error in line  

"For Each r In ActiveSheet.UsedRange"  

saying "Basic runtime error. Object variable not set"

Comment: I am working on Ubuntu and file is saved with .xls extension, does that make any difference.

Comment: I am assuming that you have created a .xls file and are creating the charts from within Excel.  This macro must run within the Excel VBA environment.  The sheet with the data must be the Selected Sheet.  Macros must be enabled.

Comment: I think I got it. LibreOffice (MSOffice counterpart in Ubuntu) support StarBasic instead of VBScript.